# Send an oobject from activity to fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an object in my main activity that stores a bunch of data from an XML document and I want to be able to access that information on several different fragments to display the information.  How can I go about doing that

Answer (score 0):

Your object can `implements java.ioSerializable` . Than you are allowed to pit an instance of this object into the android bundle with [putSerializable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#putSerializable%28java.lang.String,%20java.io.Serializable%29). Finally you can use the [setArguments](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setArguments%28android.os.Bundle%29) method to pass the bundle instance through your fragment

Comment: would be nice to add how to retrieve in the fragment to your answer

Comment: @Neil could you please rephrase?

Comment: I would like to know how to also get out the object from inside the fragment once its created :)